# Modal in stackNavigator react native expo

Tags: typescript, react-native, expo, stack-navigator

so I have an issue with stacknavigator on an expo app and trying to open a modal from it.

If the modal is on the body of the app, it works fine, with no issue, but when the modal is launched from a stack screen, most of the view is missing and when inspecting, the content is there and clickable, just not shown.

I've added a screenshot of what I mean.

It's the same piece of code for both.

This is how I added the modal to the stack

```
return (
<Stack.Navigator
  screenOptions={headerOptions}
  headerMode="screen"
  initialRouteName={'Home'}
>
  <Stack.Screen
    name="Home"
    component={TabNavigator}
    options={({ navigation, route }) => {
      let tabScene = getTabSceneName(route);
        return {
          headerTitle:
            <View>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => setSearchModalVisible(true)}
                activeOpacity={1}
              >
                <View style={styles.searchInputContainer}>
                  <SearchInput
                    pointerEvents="none"
                    placeholder={t('Search')}
                    editable={false}
                  />
                </View>
              </TouchableOpacity>
              <SearchModal
                onItemPress={(product: Product) => {
                  navigation.navigate('ProductDetails', { productHandle: product.handle });
                }}
                onSubmit={(searchKeyword: string) =>
                  navigation.navigate('SearchResults', {
                    searchKeyword,
                  })
                }
                isVisible={isSearchModalVisible}
                setVisible={setSearchModalVisible}
              />
            </View>,
          headerRight: () => (
            <HeaderIconButton
              icon="cart"
              onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ShoppingCart')}
            />
          ),
          headerStyle: {
            shadowColor: COLORS.transparent,
            elevation: 10,
          },
        };
      }
    }}
  />
  <Stack.Screen
    name="Auth"
    component={AuthScene}
    options={() => ({
      title: t('Welcome'),
    })}
  />
  <Stack.Screen
    name="ForgotPassword"
    component={ForgotPasswordScene}
    options={() => ({
      title: t('Forgot Password'),
    })}
  />
</Stack.Navigator>
);
}
```

I've attached screenshots of how it's meant to be like and the issue.

[Screenshot of missing view, when it's launched from the stack screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cjw9K.png)

[Screenshot of how it's meant to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tx6I9.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out...looks like I was using headerTitle: to return a string. Silly mistake